# Store a big image file in a binary string using NSUserDefaults is not success, any other solution?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, binary, nsuserdefaults

I try to put my customized object, which have string and an image store using NSUserDefaults, but I found out that the image is too big that I can't store. So, any other solutions to deal with it? I would like to store it in a binary format, instead of writing a file.

The error from console:
 *** -[NSKeyedUnarchiver initForReadingWithData:]: data is NULL

Thanks.

Comment: what's wrong with writing an image to a file?

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is storing it in Core Data. There you can specify to save it as binary data.

Answer (score 0):

directly from [Apple Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PropertyLists/PropertyLists.pdf).

> Many applications require a mechanism for storing information that
>   will be needed at a later time. For situations where you need to store
>   small amounts of persistent data—say less than a few hundred
>   kilobytes property lists offer a uniform and convenient means of
>   organizing, storing, and accessing the data.
>
> In some situations, the
>   property-list architecture may prove insufficient. If you need a way
>   to store large, complex graphs of objects, objects not supported by
>   the property-list architecture, or objects whose mutability settings
>   must be retained, use archiving.

you should use NSKeyedArchiver class. refer this link [saving data created by the user](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000084.php).

Answer (score -1):

Store this image in your document directory and save the path in your NSUserDefault.

You can access to the document directory like that

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; // Get documents folder
```

Comment: The document directory should only be used  for files that can not be recreated, downloaded or are user created. For the other files use the `NSCachesDirectory`. This has to do with iCloud.

Comment: I agree but storing the image in NSUserData has the same problem. We can't maybe recreate this image.

Comment: Read the [iOS Data Storage Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/) it tells you how make sure that files in the caches directory can be set to not be removed if there is a low disk space issue. You can set the `do not back up` attribute to make sure that the files remain on the device even in a low storage situation.